# Sharepoint Site Template - Custom .aspx pages

Tags: sharepoint, sitetemplate, custom-pages

I am creating a site template in Sharepoint. I also have some custom .aspx page, that I want to deploy in Layouts\myDirectory. Using my site template I will create a Web (SPWeb) that should use the custom pages and reference them by an url of the form http://site/MyWeb/MyCustomPage.aspx. How do I integrate the pages in my custom template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pages stored in the Layouts folder are Application Pages and should always only be referenced through the _layouts virtual directory

If you want to reference the page as http://site/MyWeb/MyCustomPage.aspx then it should be a Site Page

A site page can be put inside a feature or directly inside a Site Definition (even thought I recommend that you only use the Site Definition to activate features). The way you provision the page is throught the Module & File elements see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms441170.aspx)

Comment: These Site Pages, do they have to be web part pages or they can be simple asp.net pages with code-behind and user controls?

Comment: They can be both, just as long as the DLL is available to SHarePoint, either in the BIN folder or the GAC.

Comment: Think of the "pages" as files, as Per says they are provisioned through a module in the element.xml file in the feature (+1)

Answer (score 1):

A site template can only contain the contents of a single site/web. So you can't deploy files to the layouts folder using this technique.

However you can use site templates in combination with a solution package that copies your files. There is an [example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb466225.aspx). Deployment of the solution package will deploy your custom .aspx pages once. From then on they will be accessible to sites created by your site template.

Comment: My problem is not with copying the aspx file to the layouts directory. What I don't understand is how to reference them in the elements.xml file for the pages feature that will be used by the site template.